# How do I find 5 most sold products from a mongodb collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am working on a project which needs to show stats of sale to user. This is how my Cart collection looks like:

[Cart Collection snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSYhx.jpg)

The 'orderData' document contains array of products in each order. I want to get top 5 sold products from cart collection. Here is Cart schema definition:

```
const Cart = mongoose.model(
"Cart",
new mongoose.Schema({
    orderData:{type:[Object]},
    totalPrice:Number,
    createdOn:{type:Date,default:Date.now}
})
```

)

Here is sample data:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"6124ab3096873c2fa0cd4f4f"},"orderData":[{"id":"61221da34cb4a728342c0a17","title":"sports watch","price":"20"},{"id":"61221db84cb4a728342c0a1b","title":"The best hover","price":"75"},{"id":"612222e4e3ebde23dcb1b2f8","title":"Eye Liner","price":"7"}],"totalPrice":102,"createdOn":{"$date":"2021-08-24T08:17:52.249Z"},"__v":0}
```

Comment: you can `$unwind` the orderData, group by productID and sum the quantiy, the sort descending, and then limit(5) , using the aggregation framework, if try those and problems, give sample data so someone writes you the query to help

Comment: Thank you so much for help. There is no explicit quantity field for added product. a product is just added in the orderData. I added data sample for more clarification. Please have a look at it and see if you could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query finds the top 5 sold products in the card collection

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pLuJYl_foLG)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$orderData"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$orderData.id",
      "title": {
        "$first": "$orderData.title"
      },
      "totalSold": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "totalSold": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 5
  }
])
```

Comment: Man that is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!